# SonarQube MSBuild integration failed:

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube

The SonarQube MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was unable to collect the required information about your projects.

I have setup sonarqube, I have created a .bat file to execute. The SonarQube.MSBuild scanner runs.  The MS Build succeeds

*** BAT FILE IN PROJECT ROOT ***

cd c:\tutorials\udemy\sonarqubeweb
SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"CSharpTest" /d:sonar.host.url="http://localhost:9000" /d:sonar.login="7e14e692c985484a9453aca9fb79920bc83214c7"

cd C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin
MSBuild.exe C:\Tutorials\Udemy\SonarqubeWeb\SonarqubeWeb.sln /t:Rebuild

cd c:\tutorials\udemy\sonarqubeweb
SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end /d:sonar.login="7e14e692c985484a9453aca9fb79920bc83214c7"

**OUTPUT**

C:\Tutorials\Udemy\SonarqubeWeb>SonarQubeWeb.bat

C:\Tutorials\Udemy\SonarqubeWeb>cd c:\tutorials\udemy\sonarqubeweb

C:\Tutorials\Udemy\SonarqubeWeb>SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"CSharpTest" /d:sonar.host.url="http://localhost:9000" /d:sonar.login="7e14e692c985484a9453aca9fb79920bc83214c7"
SonarScanner for MSBuild 4.6.2
Using the .NET Framework version of the Scanner for MSBuild
Pre-processing started.
Preparing working directories...
03:48:16.862  Updating build integration targets...
03:48:16.942  Fetching analysis configuration settings...
03:48:17.463  Provisioning analyzer assemblies for cs...
03:48:17.464  Installing required Roslyn analyzers...
03:48:17.771  Provisioning analyzer assemblies for vbnet...
03:48:17.772  Installing required Roslyn analyzers...
03:48:17.811  Pre-processing succeeded.

C:\Tutorials\Udemy\SonarqubeWeb>cd C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin>MSBuild.exe C:\Tutorials\Udemy\SonarqubeWeb\SonarqubeWeb.sln /t:Rebuild
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
Build started 6/9/2019 3:48:17 AM.
Project "C:\Tutorials\Udemy\SonarqubeWeb\SonarqubeWeb.sln" on node 1 (Rebuild target(s)).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
The target "MvcBuildViews" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Tutorials\Udemy\SonarqubeWeb\packages\MSBuild.Mic
rosoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets.14.0.0.3\tools\VSToolsPath\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets (843,131)" does not exi
st in the project, and will be ignored.
Project "C:\Tutorials\Udemy\SonarqubeWeb\SonarqubeWeb.sln" (1) is building "C:\Tutorials\Udemy\SonarqubeWeb\SonarqubeWe
b\SonarqubeWeb.csproj" (2) on node 1 (Rebuild target(s)).

Done Building Project "C:\Tutorials\Udemy\SonarqubeWeb\SonarqubeWeb\SonarqubeWeb.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)).

Done Building Project "C:\Tutorials\Udemy\SonarqubeWeb\SonarqubeWeb.sln" (Rebuild target(s)).

**Build succeeded.**
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:04.85

cd c:\tutorials\udemy\sonarqubeweb

SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end /d:sonar.login="7e14e692c985484a9453aca9fb79920bc83214c7"
SonarScanner for MSBuild 4.6.2
Using the .NET Framework version of the Scanner for MSBuild
Post-processing started.
The SonarQube MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was unable to collect the required information about your projects.
Possible causes:
  1. The project has not been built - the project must be built in between the begin and end steps
  2. An unsupported version of MSBuild has been used to build the project. Currently MSBuild 14.0 and 15.0 are supported
  3. The begin, build and end steps have not all been launched from the same folder
  4. None of the analyzed projects have a valid ProjectGuid and you have not used a solution (.sln)
Generation of the sonar-properties file failed. Unable to complete SonarQube analysis.
03:48:23.091  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1

Answer (score 0):

See point (3) of the output from the SonarScanner.MSBuild *end* step you quoted above:

> 3. The begin, build and end steps have not all been launched from the same folder

You are changing directory before invoking MSBuild then changing it again before calling the *end* step.

Don't change the directory before calling MSBuild. If MSBuild isn't in the %Path% then just invoke it using a fully-qualified path i.e.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "C:\Tutorials\Udemy\SonarqubeWeb\SonarqubeWeb.sln" /t:Rebuild
```